# Is there a way to filter individual items within a list of values in Excel using the filter tool?

Tags: excel, list, filter, powerquery

I am unsure how to create a filter list with individual value entries. Essentially I have a column, where its cells contain multiple values (e.g. HAZOP, LOPA, etc.), but when using the filter drop down, the check boxes are for the entire cell, rather than individual values within the cell. Is there a way so that I can use the filter tool but check for certain values such as HAZOP or LOPA.

See images provided for more context:
[List in cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTLyH.png)
[Filter list options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GhZr.png)

I tried using Excel Power Query Editor as a way of creating specific filters, but I am really unsure how this program works and how to fix this problem.

Comment: Type `HAZOP` into the search box immediately above the checkboxes.